# Taking the results of a bash command and using it in python

Tags: python, bash, operating-system, command

I am trying to write a code in python that will take some information from top and put it into a file.
I want to just write the name of the application and generate the file. The problem i am having is that i can't get the output of the pidof command so i can use it in python. My code looks like this :

```
import os

a = input('Name of the application')
val=os.system('pidof ' + str(a)) 
os.system('top -d 30 | grep' + str(val) + '> test.txt')
os.system('awk '{print $10, $11}' test.txt > test2.txt')
```

The problem is that val always has 0 but the command is returning the pid i want. Any input would be great.

Comment: You have the name of the application and you want... what? Write something concerning this application into a file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First up, the use of `input()` is discouraged as it expects the user to type in valid Python expressions. Use `raw_input()` instead:

```
app = raw_input('Name of the application: ')
```

Next up, the return value from `system('pidof')` isn't the PID, it's the exit code from the `pidof` command, i.e. zero on success, non-zero on failure. You want to [capture the output](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-bin-sh-shell-backquote) of `pidof`.

```
import subprocess

# Python 2.7 only
pid = int(subprocess.check_output(['pidof', app]))

# Python 2.4+
pid = int(subprocess.Popen(['pidof', app], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0])

# Older (deprecated)
pid = int(os.popen('pidof ' + app).read())
```

The next line is missing a space after the `grep` and would have resulted in a command like `grep1234`. Using the string formatting operator `%` will make this a little easier to spot:

```
os.system('top -d 30 | grep %d > test.txt' % (pid))
```

The third line is badly quoted and should have caused a syntax error. Watch out for the single quotes inside of single quotes.

```
os.system("awk '{print $10, $11}' test.txt > test2.txt")
```

Comment: This is the answer you want. You can abstract it into a function if you desire. However note that you may possibly need to call .strip() to remove newlines on the output: .communicate()[0].strip() -- you don't need to in this case, since int('12\n')==12

Comment: Thank you for the solution it works now. You help me a lot and again thank you for your fast time responce. I am using python3 and the raw_input it's not supported or i don't know if has a new form.

Comment: the equivalent in python3 of raw_input is input there is no equivalent of input of 2.X

Answer (score 2):

Instead of os.system, I recommend you to use the subprocess module: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess

With that module, you can communicate (input and output) with a shell. The documentation explains the details of how to use it.

Hope this helps!