# Toggle process with Python-script (kill when running, start when not running)

Tags: python, linux, shell, scripting, xbmc

I'm currently running an OpenELEC (XBMC) installation on a Raspberry Pi and installed a tool named "Hyperion" which takes care of the connected Ambilight. I'm a total noob when it comes to Python-programming, so here's my question:

How can I run a script that checks if a process with a specific string in its name is running and:

- kill the process when it's running
- start the process when it's not running

The goal of this is to have one script that toggles the Ambilight. Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to have a look at the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module which can run shell commands from Python.  For instance, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python).  You can then get the [stdout from the shell command to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514751/pipe-subprocess-standard-output-to-a-variable).  I suspect you are going to need the [`pidof`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?pidof) shell command.

The basic idea would be along the lines of:

```
import subprocess

try:
    subprocess.check_output(["pidof", "-s", "-x", "hyperiond"])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    # spawn the process using a shell command with subprocess.Popen
    subprocess.Popen("hyperiond")
else:
    # kill the process using a shell command with subprocess.call
    subprocess.call("kill %s" % output)
```

I've tested this code in Ubuntu with `bash` as the process and it works as expected. In your comments you note that you are getting `file not found` errors.  You can try putting the complete path to `pidof` in your `check_output` call.  This can be found using `which pidof` from the terminal. The code for my system would then become

```
    subprocess.check_output(["/bin/pidof", "-s", "-x", "hyperiond"])
```

Your path may differ.  On windows adding `shell=True` to the `check_output` arguments fixes this issue but I don't think this is relevant for Linux.

Comment: I just tried the first three lines of your code and it gives me the following result: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./toggleAmbilight.py", line 6, in <module>
    result = subprocess.check_output("pidof hyperiond", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "./Lib/subprocess.py", line 536, in check_output
ValueError: stdout argument not allowed, it will be overridden.` And idea what's wrong?

Comment: Oops - I'd left the arguments for `call()` in the example by mistake.  It should be better now. I'm fairly certain `pidof` returns `None` if the process is not found but you may need to investigate this.

Comment: Hmm, if I use the updated code with e.g. "ls" it works fine, but when I put in "pidof" or other commands like "time" it throughs various error messages.

Comment: Hard to provide an intelligent response to "various error messages"! Have a look at the answer to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744980/taking-the-results-of-a-bash-command-and-using-it-in-python - and see if that is useful

Comment: e.g. `pid = int(subprocess.check_output(['pidof', app]))`

Comment: I also tried the solution from the other thread, both with Raspberry Pi and my Macbook, but the errors always look like this:   `File "./Lib/subprocess.py", line 537, in check_output
  File "./Lib/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
  File "./Lib/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: I've made some edits which have been tested on my Ubuntu setup and are working as expected

Answer (score 1):

Thanks so much for your help @will-hart, I finally got it working. Needed to change some details because the script kept saying that "output" is not defined. Here's how it now looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
from subprocess import call

try:
    subprocess.check_output(["pidof", "hyperiond"])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        subprocess.Popen(["/storage/hyperion/bin/hyperiond.sh", "/storage/.config/hyperion.config.json"])
else:
    subprocess.call(["killall", "hyperiond"])
```